# Using directory in VirtualHost server name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, virtualhost

So this is what I am trying to accomplish :

1. If the server name is www.mynewapp.com the proxy pass or document root should be http://localhost:8080/mynewapp/
2. If server name is www.mynewapp.com/app, the proxy pass or document root should be http://localhost:8080/app.

But as server name can't contain directory (www.mynewapp.com/app), I am unable to figure it out. If I use `Alias '/app'`, even www.mynewapp.com will go to /app version of document root.

My current virtual host looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerName www.mynewapp.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/mynewapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/mynewapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works for point 1. I tried using RewriteRules to cover both cases like this :

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerName www.mynewapp.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "^/app/(.*)$" "/app/$1"
    RewriteRule "^/(.*)$" "/mynewapp/$1"
</VirtualHost>
```

But I am unable to get the regex right. Any help, either by regex or by creating 2 different virtual hosts to solve both points, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerName www.mynewapp.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8888/app
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8888/app
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/mynewapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/mynewapp/
</VirtualHost>
```